# Onclick event for all the control present inside the div using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am using Jquery Data Table. How to do onclick event for all the tags with in the div tag. Now onclick event is working for anchor tag which is inside the div. But for anchor tag with the span. Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my Jquery and HTML code:

```
 $(function () {
                $('body').on('click', '#myDataTable_paginate a', function () {
                    alert("Inside");
            });

<div id="myDataTable_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
        <a id="myDataTable_first" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" tabindex="0">First</a>
        <a id="myDataTable_previous" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
        <span>
    <a class="paginate_active" tabindex="0">1</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">2</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">3</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">4</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">5</a>
    </span>
        <a id="myDataTable_next" class="next paginate_button" tabindex="0">Next</a>
        <a id="myDataTable_last" class="last paginate_button" tabindex="0">Last</a>
        </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: your code should work for inner anchor elements as well.

Comment: No, its not working for anchor tag with in span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just bind the click event to the div myDataTable_paginate" like this:

```
$("#myDataTable_paginate").click(function(e){
   alert(e.target.id);
});
```

As you can see in the alert i put in the fiddle, you can get the id of the clicked object via `e.target.id`.

If you want to get the content of one tag like the page numbers, you can also get the value with `e.target.innerHTML`

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jy9cxkg1/)

Comment: This is working fine. Thanks for saving my time. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').on('click', '#myDataTable_paginate>a', function () {
     alert("Inside Div");
});

$('body').on('click', '#myDataTable_paginate span a', function () {
    alert("Inside span");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDataTable_paginate" class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers">
        <a id="myDataTable_first" class="first paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" tabindex="0">First</a>
        <a id="myDataTable_previous" class="previous paginate_button paginate_button_disabled" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
        <span>
    <a class="paginate_active" tabindex="0">1</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">2</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">3</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">4</a>
    <a class="paginate_button" tabindex="0">5</a>
    </span>
        <a id="myDataTable_next" class="next paginate_button" tabindex="0">Next</a>
        <a id="myDataTable_last" class="last paginate_button" tabindex="0">Last</a>
        </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply:) Inside div is working fine. But Inside span is not working:(